# Number of cores in AWS r4.16xlarge cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I'm having a 10 node AWS r4.16xlarge cluster, Under the Executor tab in spark UI, the number under "cores" is being different every time I spin the cluster, sometimes it shows 200, some other time it shows 300. I'm not sure whether it is related to dynamic allocation. What I would like to know is the total number of available cores in the cluster configuration, so that I can set the spark parameters accordingly.

[image]

Comment: check the aws documentation or notice like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/aws/new-next-generation-r4-memory-optimized-ec2-instances/).

Comment: In r4.16xlarge you have 64 cores per node, so with 10 nodes  you will have 640 cores which you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have 64 cores per node, you have totally 640 cores in your cluster to use. However, you should not assume that you can use all 640 cores since cores might be reserved in different cluster manager. For example, in Spark on Kubernetes, you need to reserve at least one core for the proxy and DNS in each node. If you use some monitoring solution like Prometheus, you can check your resource utilization.

It's related to dynamic allocation if you have different number of cores in your application when you submit your Spark application. You should set `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to `false` and configure by `spark.driver.cores` and `spark.executor.cores`.